# How to use .FormulaR1C1 Function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the .FormulaR1C1 function for the following forumula: =VLOOKUP(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-1),Key!$A$17:$I$29,8,FALSE)

When I enter it into my code it does not work?

```
Option Explicit
Sub CalcColB()

Dim x As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For x = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
 Select Case (Cells(x, 6))
 Case "Net 75 from 1st of following month"
 Cells(x, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-1),Key!$A$17:$I$29,8,FALSE)"

 Case "F"
 Cells(x, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*1000"
 Case Else
 Cells(x, 2).Formula = "="""""
 End Select
Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: For starters, `Key!$A$17:$I$29` is not in R1C1 notation.

Comment: Oh okay, I look that notation up. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For R1C1:

```
Cells(x, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Key!R17C1:R29C9,8,FALSE)"
```

Comment: Defintely upvoted this one. Seeing the `OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS` hurts inside a little.

Comment: @BigBen every time someone uses `OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS` a unicorn dies :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use **.Formula**:

```
Sub poiuy()
    Range("A1").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-1),Key!$A$17:$I$29,8,FALSE)"
End Sub
```